# Проблема передачи данных с jsp страницы в контроллер

Tags: jsp, servlet, controller

На странице есть товары, приведенный код отвечает за кнопку "подробнее" на товаре.

```
<c:url value="/aboutCourse" var="aboutCourse" />
 <form action="${aboutCourse}" method="POST" >
 <input type='hidden' name='courseId' value=${course.id}/>
 </form>
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="${aboutCourse}">Подробнее<c:out value="${course.id}"/></a>
```

По нажатию на кнопу информация course.id должна передаваться в контроллер (на странице она отображается)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aboutCourse", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String aboutCourse(
    @RequestParam(required = false) long courseId){
CustomCourse course = courseService.getCourseById(courseId);
return "aboutCourse";
}
```

Но при переходе по ссылке получаем:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Optional long parameter 'courseId' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.

Есть мнения почему параметр не передается, почему хочет присвоить null и что вообще происходит?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете как метод GET - напишите так: `href="${aboutCourse}?courseId=${course.id}"`. Если же хотите использовать POST, то отправляйте форму через `submit`.

Comment: Использовал GET. Помогло. Можете уточнить конструкцию, если необходимо передать сразу несколько аргументов?

Comment: Соответственно: `?param1=value1&param2=value2&paramN=valueN`. Вам стоит почитать хотя бы о методах GET и POST поподробней.